# how to reset page to initial scale when user click on the link?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, html, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have meta tag as below:

When you go to the site, it loads it to the initial scale 0.3 and then user cam zoom to max 2 & zoom out till the initial scale 0.3. These all work fine as expected. The only issue i am having is, when you zoom-in the current page and click on the link from current page to go to another page, the new page appears as zoom-in. How can i set page to initial scale on every call?

Also if you type the url in the address bar then the page appears to initial scale. Only when you click the link or go from menu bar & you have zoom ghen the next page appears as zoom.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem by first adding an id to the scale meta in the head of the site:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"  id="scale1" />
```

Then I on the links I want that scale reset I add:

```
$('#scale1').remove();
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"  id="scale1" />');
```

It works fine on Andriod, but not on iOS. Maybe someone could give further feedback.